# C++ Is live PCM fft audio processing with OpenAL?

Tags: c++, multithreading, audio, openal, pcm

I'm working on a project that will involve having to process PCM audio data through fft as its being played, preferably in sync. I'm using a linux g++ compiler and currently reading and playing audio data using OpenAL.

My question is this: is there a better way to process PCM audio data with an fft live as the audio is playing then using threads? If not, then what threading library would be best to use for these purposes.

this is my function that loads the wave data into an array of bytes, these can later be cast to ints for processing and all I use to play the data is OpenAL.

```
    char* loadWAV(const char* fn, int& chan, int& samplerate, int& bps, int& size){
        char buffer[4];
        ifstream in(fn, ios::binary);
        in.read(buffer, 4);                                                             //ChunkID "RIFF"
        if(strncmp(buffer, "RIFF", 4) != 0){ 
                cerr << "this is not a valid wave file";
                return NULL;
        }   
        in.read(buffer,4);                                                              //ChunkSize 
        in.read(buffer,4);                                                              //Format "WAVE"
        in.read(buffer,4);                                                              // "fmt "
        in.read(buffer,4);                                                              // 16
        in.read(buffer,2);                                                              // 1
        in.read(buffer,2);                                                              // NUMBER OF CHANNELS
        chan = convertToInt(buffer,2);
        in.read(buffer,4);                                                              // SAMPLE RATE
        samplerate = convertToInt(buffer,4);
        in.read(buffer,4);                                                              // ByteRate
        in.read(buffer,2);                                                              // BlockAlign
        in.read(buffer,2);                                                              // bits per sample
        bps = convertToInt(buffer,2);
        in.read(buffer,4);                                                              // "data"
        in.read(buffer,4);
        size = convertToInt(buffer,4);
        char * data = new char[size];
        in.read(data,size);
        return data;
}
```

thank you for any and all help.

edit: to anyone who might be interested I wrote the function using [this](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) as a reference to know
how a WAV file is formated

Comment: Why are you concerned that threads would not work?  What precisely are you worried about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you hoping to perform the FFT using OpenAL? I don't know if that's possible. Your code will likely be performing the FFT.

You don't need to explicitly set up any threads. However, your audio output library will probably do so on your behalf. I'm not familiar with OpenAL, but the way that a lot of audio libraries operate is by letting you specify a callback that will feed more audio into the output. Thus, your main program will load audio from the audio file, stuff it into a buffer (likely protected by a mutex) for the audio callback to read, compute an FFT over the audio window, and perhaps visualize the data for the user.

Again, the audio library will probably be managing the threading so you don't need to worry about the exact threading implementation or library. But be sure to manage shared data correctly with a mutex.

Comment: btw would you happen to know if I could just pass the byte array of PCM data to an FFT algorithm as is?

Comment: This all depends on what the FFT function wants to see. If the function wants an array of C shorts (signed 16-bit quantities), then that probably matches up well with the data from the WAV file sitting on disk, assuming you have a little endian CPU (and you probably do). If, however, the FFT function wants an array of C floats (32-bit single-precision floating point numbers), you will need to do a sequence of conversions first.

Comment: Does it being a WAV require it to be parsed in a specific way?

Comment: A WAV file can store lots of different types of data. You will need to take that into account when reading the WAV file (reject types of data you don't know how to parse).

Comment: Don't be afraid to post new questions that dig into this topic. As you can see from my handle, I love talking about this stuff.

Comment: Well.. actually there is something. http://www.openal.org/documentation/openal-1.1-specification.pdf at the top of page 47 there is an attribute called AL_FREQUENCY, the doc says that this value can be accessed through the buffer but is it the frequency I need to do live processing or is it an unchanging number descriptive of the WAV in its entirety? edit: also is this the same frequency i'd get if I passed data through an fft?

Comment: Based on the context where AL_FREQUENCY appears (alongside AL_BITS, AL_SIZE, and AL_CHANNELS), it describes the sample rate (measured in Hz, which is a measure of frequency) on the sample buffer.

Comment: How would I extract a frequency spectrum kind of data from my char* data variable?

Comment: Shove the data through an FFT function. This thread is getting a bit long and if you need more advice on this matter, it would probably be better to open a new question which can potentially draw more attention.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I'm playing around with different generated 1 second samples to compare the data.